# jquery animate then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Struggling a bit with jquery animate.

At the moment, if I continue to click button, clearly it shifts the object to the right 50px every time

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#object" ).animate({opacity: 1,right: "+=50",}, 500, function() {}
);
```

Is there a way of ensuring that one click moves it once, then a second click does not move it?

ie. a rule that moves it to right:50px and thats it, rather than + 50px?

Any assistance hugely appreciated!!

Comment: You should check out this plugin.. it uses CSS3 transitions for smoother animation and works great! http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$( ".button" ).one('click',function() {
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WB742/)

Comment: Sorry - don't think I explained myself very well - is it possible, to move it to a specific absolute right position on click? sorry I didn't word it quite right

Answer (score 0):

You can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$(".button").one('click', function () {
    $("#object").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: "+=50",
    }, 500, function () {

    });
});
```

or I'd suggest you to disable the button to let your users know about your intention here:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#object").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: "+=50",
    }, 500, function () {
        $this.prop("disabled",true);
    });
});
```